# boost create_directories failed on MAC OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, boost

I built a very simple app on MAC OS X using XCODE 5. I am trying to create a directory using boost::filesystem library. It compiled and built ok. But create_directories seems has some problems.I copied the call stack below. Anyone has idea of what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const string dir_path = "/Users/js/temp/";
    boost::filesystem::path dir(dir_path);
    boost::filesystem::create_directories(dir); 
    return 0;
}
```

Trace:

```
------call stack----
#0  0x000000010000ddd0 in std::string::size() const [inlined] at /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:606
#1  0x000000010000ddcd in boost::filesystem::path::m_parent_path_end() const at /Users/shuj/boost_1_55_0/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:328
#2  0x000000010000e645 in boost::filesystem::path::parent_path() const at /Users/shuj/boost_1_55_0/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:349
#3  0x0000000100009189 in boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*) at /Users/shuj/boost_1_55_0/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:931
#4  0x000000010000199f in boost::filesystem::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&) at /Users/shuj/boost_1_55_0/lib/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:399
#5  0x000000010000110b in main at /Users//Desktop/Projects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/main.cpp:24

failed on this line
size() const
      { return _M_rep()->_M_length; }
```

Comment: I am not sure what's the problem but you can also try:
`try{
        if (boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir_path)){
            std::cerr <<"Directory with dir_path!"<< std::endl;
        }}
    catch (boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }`